# Openssl: How to transfer certificates signed by CA?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have created a CA using OpenSSL. Now i want my server to send Certificate Signing Request(CSR) to CA and receive the signed certificate.
My question is, Is there any specific method provided by OpenSSL to transfer the CSR and signed certificate between the CA and server? Or i should just send the CSR to CA using any method (e.g. my own client-server program that sends CSR and receives signed certificate) and receive the signed certificate in same way.

Hope I have clearly stated my question. Waiting for response.

Regards

Comment: What confuses me is your first statement "I have created a CA using OpenSSL." I think what you meant was you created a CSR, is that right?

Comment: I meant, on one machine i created a Root Certificate Authority which will receive CSR from users(other machines) and will generate Certificate based upon CSR. Now how should i transfer CSR from user to Root CA and retrieve back user.crt(certificate generated by CA). Is there any specific method? I think now i have stated clearly :)